# Como recargar una página Web

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tengo la siguiente duda:

Suponiendo que tengo dos archivos: `myweb.php`, en donde se tiene un boton que realiza la función de abrir en una nueva pestaña `myweb2.php`; El archivo `myweb2.php` se ejecuta cuando se da click en el boton de `myweb.php`.

```
<button id="myButton">Abrir</button>

$(function(){
  $("#myButton").click(function(){
    window.open("myweb2.php");
  });
});
```

Lo que busco es poder abrir una vez `myweb2.php` y al dar click de nuevo en el boton de `myweb.php` recargar `myweb2.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ello deberas primero guardar la instancia de tu ventana de manera global, para poder luego usarla y recargarla cuando des click a tu boton:

```js
$(function(){
  let ventanaAAbrir;
  $("#myButton").click(function(){
    //Si no esta abierta la ventana la abrimos y guardamos su instancia, de lo contrario
    //lo que haremos sera que cada vez que se llame al metodo se recargue la pagina 2
    if(!ventanaAAbrir){
      ventanaAAbrir = window.open("myweb2.php");
    }else{
      ventanaAAbrir.location.reload();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton">Abrir</button>
```

Naturalmente no veras ningun resultado aqui mismo si lo ejecutas en stackoverflow, puesto que las ventanas emergentes normalmente son bloqueadas, si deseas ver el resultado deberas comprobar este codigo con tus propios archivos locales.

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudo mucho tu aporte.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de hacer la redirección necesitas un observador de eventos, para que así cuando des click en la página 1, el cambio lo pueda detectar la página 2.

Para crear el observador podrías hacerlo a través de WebSockets, con contadores de tiempo o incluso localStorage, queda a tu decisión.

De esa manera cuando se dispare un evento en la página 2, lo puedas detectar y puedes hacer un:

```
location.reload();
```

Lee la documentación y cuando lleves algo si tienes un error o necesitas ayuda, puedes publicarlo en StackOverflow.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su comentario. Agradezco que se tomen el tiempo.